# Preventing Customization of MFMailComposeViewController Background Image

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Currently we are using this block of code that customizes the UINavigationBar background image throughout our app:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar(MyExtensions)

- (UIImage *)barBackground {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"GlobalTitleBackground.png"];
}

- (void)didMoveToSuperview {
    //iOS5 only
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
    {
        [self setBackgroundImage:[self barBackground] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
}

//this doesn't work on iOS5 but is needed for iOS4 and earlier
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //draw image
    [[self barBackground] drawInRect:rect];
}

@end
```

In general, this works great. The problem I'm encountering is that when I create a MFMailComposeViewController, it's background also gets customized.

Therefore, is it possible, given the code that I have right now, to do the customization on all UINavigationBars **except the UINavigationBar created by the MFMailComposeViewController**?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to filter out that specific navigation controller by using the view.tag property.

When you create your MFMailComposeViewController to add a tag to the nav bar.

For example:

```
//In other VC
MFMailController *mailVC = [[MFMailController alloc] init];
mailVC.navigationBar.tag = 5678;

//In @implementation UINavigationBar(MyExtensions)
- (UIImage *)barBackground {
    if (self.tag != 5678)
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"GlobalTitleBackground.png"];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: What other solutions are besides this one?

Comment: You can remove the custom navigation bar for that specific view MFMailController.  [mailVC setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];